# jPanel messing with Bootstraps modal window

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jpanel, z-index

I have a problem with displaying modal windows in Twitter Bootstrap after installing the jPanelMenu jQuery plugin.

The problem is that the backdrop intended to go behind the model appears in front of the modal.

The z-index of the backdrop is 1040 and the z-index of the modal window is 1050 and both are set to position:fixed, so everything should display right.

I found several past topics about issues with the stacking order of the modal backdrop, but none which involved jPanel and I was not able to use any of the suggested solutions.

The problem is clearly introduced by running the jPanel plugin, as it disappears when the script-library is removed. But I can't figure out how to resolve it with jPanel enabled, as it does not react to changes in z-index, excepts for when you run the z-index of the backdrop down to < 2 and it disappears altogehter. I made a JSFiddle here that displays the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/funkylaundry/DebF6/3/light/

```
<body>

  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
          <p class="navbar-text pull-right">
            Logged in as
            <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Username</a>
          </p>
          <ul class="nav">
            <li>
              <a class="menu-trigger" href="#">Menu</a>
            </li>
            <li class="active">
              <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse --> </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span9">
        <div class="hero-unit">
          <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
          <p>
            This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called the hero unit and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.
          </p>
          <p>
            <!-- Button to trigger modal -->
            <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>
              <hr>
              <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-large menu-trigger">Launch jPanel Menu</a>
          </p>
            <!-- Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>One fine body…</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
  </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span4">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>
              Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.
            </p>
            <p>
              <a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a>
            </p>
          </div>
          <!--/span-->
          <div class="span4">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>
              Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.
            </p>
            <p>
              <a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a>
            </p>
          </div>
          <!--/span-->
          <div class="span4">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>
              Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.
            </p>
            <p>
              <a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a>
            </p>
          </div>
          <!--/span--> </div>
        <!--/row-->
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span4">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>
              Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.
            </p>
            <p>
              <a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a>
            </p>
          </div>
          <!--/span-->
          <div class="span4">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>
              Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.
            </p>
            <p>
              <a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a>
            </p>
          </div>
          <!--/span-->
          <div class="span4">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>
              Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.
            </p>
            <p>
              <a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a>
            </p>
          </div>
          <!--/span--> </div>
        <!--/row--> </div>
      <!--/span--> </div>
    <!--/row-->

    <hr>

    <footer>
      <p>&copy; Company 2013</p>
    </footer>

  </div>
  <nav class="span3" id="menu" style="display:none;">
    <div id="navigator" class="navigation row-fluid">
      <div class="navbox">

        <ul class="nav nav-list">
          <li>
            <a href="/">Listen</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/Playlist">Playlists</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Charts</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/Account/Manage">My Profile</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>

    </div>

  </nav>



  <!--/.fluid-container-->

  <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
  <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.jpanelmenu.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script>
      $('document').ready(function(){
        var jPM = $.jPanelMenu();
        jPM.on();
      });
    </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

The jPanelMenu plugin pushes everything into a `.jPanelMenu-panel` div, which has a z-index of 2. This ends up conflicting with the z-index of the Bootstrap modal elements, as demonstrated.

jPanelMenu has an option called [excludedPanelContent](http://jpanelmenu.com/#options-excludedPanelContent):

> > A selector string specifying which elements within the `<body>` element should not be pushed into `.jPanelMenu-panel`. The selector string may contain any selector, not just tags.
> >
> > Generally, `<style>` and `<script>` tags should not be moved from their original location, but in certain circumstances (mostly advertising), `<script>` tags may need to move with the page content.
> >
> > > **Data Type:** `string`
> > >
> > > **Default Value:** `style, script`

A solution would be to exclude the topmost element within your `<body>` that contains the Bootstrap modal markup. In your case, I would first relocate the modal markup so that it's a top level element within your `<body>`, and then exclude `.modal`:

```
var jPM = $.jPanelMenu({
  excludedPanelContent: 'style, script, .modal'
});
```

Relocating the modal markup is necessary so that it can be excluded independently; your main content divs still need to be pushed into `.jPanelMenu-panel` in order for the jPanel Menu toggle to work properly.

See the updated fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/DebF6/7/

Answer (score 0):

Just add this css code into your site.

```
.modal-open .jPanelMenu-panel{position:static!important;transform:none!important;}
```

It will disabled jPanelMenu overlay when opening bootstrap modal so prevent conflict between them.

Good luck!